# tomcat vs own server

Tags: java, tomcat

Considering the overall performance is the most important concern and I'm wondering if writing a simple web server in Java is enough to handle production.
(I'm talking about serving java-generated content)

Is it reasonable to expect a decent written socket application can offer same reliability as Tomcat's?

(a difficulty I might think of is overcoming browsers' bugs)

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest to first look for an other http server before even contemplating to write your own. It is not a trivial job to write a compliant HTTP server that performance well and rolling your own will only add to your maintenance burden. In short: just don't write one yourself.

Comment: It's easy to think of disadvantages of writing your own server - it's more work, it might not be as fast, it might not be as reliable, it might not be as compatible. Are there any advantages? I can't think of any.

Comment: @Tom_Anderson Pride ? :-D

Comment: Yep, pride is one reason. Another one is that my OCD keeps me away from pieces I cannot efficiently control.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give importance to the word ***production*** here. Writing an indigenous web server would error prone and is like re-inventing the wheel.

Handling Concurrency, Security, compliance to specifications, optimal performance under heavy load, Connectors etc will pose major problems, esp when you want the server to be ***production-ready***

Testing involved in delivering a good enough reliable web server will be huge.

Additionally, there are already reliable webservers available like tomcat v7, jetty which are configurable enough to optimize performance and have sufficient hooks to customize as well. So IMO, it's a NO.

Answer (score 2):

As it comes to speed and reliability, my web server of choice is [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org)

Tomcat is a great web server, but has a bigger footprint. But that depends on how much container functionality you'lll need

If your choice is 'Tomcat or mine', you'll have to consider that Thread Safety / Concurrency issues are not simple to handle under high load, and need some care to design.

You could have a look at [Simple Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/) which claims to be a fast HTTP Server, but which I never personnaly used.

Comment: We have an app using Simple where i work. It is simple to program against, and it works.

Comment: I'm interested in the real-world "footprint" of Tomcat versus Jetty. Can you give more detail, @Grooveek?

Comment: Fair enough, it seems a consensus that it's hard to beat an existing web server. Thanks! Also, the question of real footprint seems interesting; will anyone who experienced both share the learnings?

Comment: That's pretty difficult to say. It depends on the application deployed. We've deployed a fairly simple webservice app running in an embedded Tomcat in another java application. Then we've tested by replacing it with Jetty, and we gained roughly 60MB on startup on a 64bit JVM. Curves under load were also in favor of jetty for this particular use. You should run your tests in your specific case.